# MPI_send and MPI_recv is hanging when count > 64 for MPI_FLOAT

Tags: cuda, mpi, openmpi

I am encountering a problem when using `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`. when the number of `count <= 64`, the overall problem runs without any problem, while for `count > 64` the program is hanging.

is there any solution to this? the address is on the global memory address on two GPUs.

Here is the code I use. When I set the `n<=64` it works, otherwise, it hangs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *d_msg;
    int myrank, tag=99;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

    const int n = 65; // <-- number of FLOATs
    const int num_GPUs = 2;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_msg, n*sizeof(float)); 

    MPI_Send(d_msg, n, MPI_FLOAT, (myrank + 1)%num_GPUs, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(d_msg, n, MPI_FLOAT, (myrank - 1 + num_GPUs)%num_GPUs, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, just try to use different send and recv buffer, it still hangs when count > 64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPI_Send` is a blocking call. Your processes both sit in `MPI_Send` waiting for the other to call `MPI_Recv`. `MPI_Send` *can* be non-blocking for small messages, which is why it works with <= 64 elements.

Possible solutions are:

- Call `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` in alternating order on the communicating ranks
- Use `MPI_Sendrecv`
- Use non-blocking communication (`MPI_Isend`/`MPI_Irecv`)

The easiest here is probably to just use `MPI_Sendrecv` and replace the `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` calls with

```
MPI_Sendrecv(d_msg, n, MPI_FLOAT, (myrank + 1)%num_GPUs, tag,
             d_msg, n, MPI_FLOAT, (myrank - 1 + num_GPUs)%num_GPUs, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, I have one more question about the `tag`, how should I set its value for different point-to-point communication, and also would its value would potentially trigger the blocking?

Comment: `MPI_Recv` only matches messages sent with the same tag (or any tag with `MPI_ANY_TAG`). You can trigger a deadlock if you're not careful. In practice many programs don't bother setting different tags for different communications and just set it to 0, relying on the message order instead (MPI guarantees that messages from the same source with the same tag are matched in the exact order they were sent).